# Tailwindcss to highlight current active named link in the same page?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have sticky menu with some anchor links that escort the user to the appropriate area on a page. However, I seem to be unable to style the menu links based on a user's position in the page.

Can this be done with TailwindCSS? If so, how? I was unsuccessful trying :hover, :active and :visited modifiers.

```
<!-- simplified sticky menu example -->
<a href="#part_1" class="active:font-black">link 1</a>
<a href="#part_2" class="active:font-black">link 2</a>

<!-- simplified content areas -->
<div>
  <a name="part_1">Area 1</a>
  ...
</div>
<div>
  <a name="part_2">Area 2</a>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its possible with Tailwind, maybe not. Solved it using some good old jQuery. Maybe its of use to someone in the future.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    var areas = $('a[name*="home_"]'); // adjust to your selector prefix
    var links = $('a[href*="#home_"]'); // adjust to your selector prefix
    var tolerance = 40; // in px, adjust to your preferences
    var posY = $(this).scrollTop() + tolerance;
    var scrolledBy = [];

    $.each(areas, function (index) {
        var areaY = $(this).offset().top;
        var selector = 'a[href="#' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]';

        // anywhere in the viewport
        if (areaY < posY) {
            scrolledBy.push(selector);
        }

        // user hit scroll bottom
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() && index + 1 == areas.length) {
            scrolledBy.push(selector);
        }
    });

    if (scrolledBy.length > 0) {
        $.each(links, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('font-black');
        });
        $(scrolledBy[scrolledBy.length - 1]).addClass('font-black');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying with Tailwindcss modifiers without luck as well but the way I have been able to make it work is simply by adding custom CSS for the pseudo-classes, which seems like far less code than using jQuery.

```
a {
  color: currentColor;
}
a:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

or if using a framework such as Nuxtjs or Vuejs you can add CSS to the scoped style tag for it:

```
.router-link-active {
  color: blue;
}
```